# oauth2 - How does resource server know if user authorized?

Tags: oauth

I've been reading articles on google but none of them explained the problem to me. There is this image in the digitalocean's article that I would like to use to explain:

[image]

So I don't understand steps 5and 6. When auth server returns access token, this is used to retrieve data from resource server. But how does resource server know if the access token is really valid? Does it ask authorization server if token is valid?

For example, what will happen if I come up with some random access token and send a request to resource server with this token? How does it know that the token is not valid?

Answer (score 3):

Each Authorization server has its own way of creating its access tokens. The resource server using the authorization knows this method and is able to validate it as needed.

Standard oauth servers all have a discovery doc.  This document tells how it creates its tokens.

https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

The keys used can be found [jwks_uri](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs)

- User (Resource owner)  - Someone who owns data
- Resource server  (API) - a system that has storage of the User (Resource owner) data.
- Application (Client) - The application wishing to access the data owned by the user.
- Authorization server - Is the Oauth2 or identity server.

**Story**

I as a developer create super awesome google analytics app `(Application (Client))`.  I set up my application in `(Authorization server)` and get a client id and client secret.

When You `(User (Resource owner))` run my application you get a login screen followed by a consent screen

[image]

My application `Google Analytics windows` would like to access your `google analytics data` via the Google analytics api `(Resource server  (API))`

If you say yes then the Authorization server will return an access token to `Application (Client)` which it can use to access Google anlaytics api `(Resource server  (API))`

Comment: so RS and AS are two separate servers, and the resource server has access to authorization server and it validates the token every time a call is executed towards it?

Comment: Yes the access token is going to be validated by the RS every time you try and use it.   It does not need to contact the AS to check if its valid it can do that itself.

Comment: And how exactly does it validate it? I have trouble understanding that. If AS was the one to create it, how does RS know if its valid?

Comment: when its decrypted it contains a time stamp so the server knows its not to old.   It also contains the proper scopes needed by the API as well as the originating authority.

Comment: Following on, it does not mean a public key is needed?

Comment: @thebluephantom depends on the auth server really public key is normally only needed if no other token is present. Its just used to identify an application accessing the api, even for public data to ensure that if the application floods the system requesting public data they can be locked out

Comment: @DaImTo thx. Think i got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Validating the access token in the resource server is usually out of OAuth specification's scope.
There are two ways to do this,

- Invoke the introspection endpoint of the authorization server with the access token. You can determine the validity by the response from this (eg: active parameter being true).
- Decrypt the token manually at the resource server. You can check the parameters in the access token and validate the token. However, the parameters in the token might vary depending on the authorization server you use. If the token is in JWT format, you can easily use a library like nimbusds or auth0 to validate the signature and other claims.

Hope this helps.